# postgres making a primary key string+integer

Tags: postgresql

I want to make a primary key like:

```
ABCD000012018, ABCD000022018, ABCD000032018
```

and reset to 00001 every year, so in 2019 it will become **ABCD000012019**

So

- what is the best way of doing it.
- should i make another table to store counter and year parts.
- if i made other table then shoud i automatically reset year and counter (then i have to depend on server date and time) OR set counter and year manually.

Answer (score 0):

I would not make this my primary key. This looks more like an external representation to me.

One idea I have is to use a regular numeric counter as primary key and also store the current year in each row. Then keep a second table where you store the minimal number for each year.

On output, join with the second table and subtract that minimal number for the year from the primary key and generate the value you want to have on the fly.

Here is a small example:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
   id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
   year smallint DEFAULT extract(year FROM current_timestamp),
   label text
);

CREATE TABLE min_id_per_year(
   year smallint PRIMARY KEY,
   min_id bigint NOT NULL
);
```

At the beginning of each year, you add a row to `min_id_per_year`:

```
INSERT INTO min_id_per_year VALUES (2018, 1);
```

Now we insert two rows:

```
INSERT INTO t (label) VALUES ('label one'), ('label two');
```

This is how you can generate the IDs you want while you query from the table:

```
SELECT 'ABCD' || to_char(t.id - m.min_id + 1, '00000FM') || year::text AS id,
       label
FROM t
   JOIN min_id_per_year m USING (year);

      id       |   label   
---------------+-----------
 ABCD000012018 | label one
 ABCD000022018 | label two
(2 rows)
```

Comment: I have added an example.